# Handle dynamic html form with htmlUnit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

Background

1. I am using htmlUnit to simulate user behavior in a certain page
2. I am reaching to a login page which I need to enter the user credentials

Issue:

1. The form that I am suppose to fill in the details dynamically changes and pushes new input fields with value that changes upon each char inserted.
2. This input field has several event listeners which as far as I was able to find from Chrome debugging the keypress event is the most relevant to me as this what ultimately generates the updates value
3. I am getting the following errors when the page "loads":
   [User1st] An error occurred while extracting lang code TypeError: Cannot call method "getAttribute" of undefined

   4.c.g.h.javascript.StrictErrorReporter     : runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName= https://???/jquery-1.10.2.min.js] line=[3] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]

some code:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(WEBSITE_URL);
        HtmlForm loginForm = page.getFormByName("login");
        HtmlTextInput userIdField = loginForm.getInputByName("USERID");
        HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = loginForm.getInputByName("USERPASSWORD");
        userIdField.type("ID");
        passwordField.setText("PASSWORD");
```

What I am doing next is simply iterating the form input fields and see their value.

How can I make sure that all related js code really getting executed if any?

Comment: Please post the WEBSITE_URL to enable us to reproduce your case.

Comment: ended up using selenium

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this helps but just letting the script sleeps work for me. This probably gives time loading all the js scripts.

```java
Thread.sleep(2000);
```